# How to locate and list peaks of a specified height in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

Is it possible to calculate a list of peaks for a specific area given a specific prominence (say 200 meters)?

If so can this be achieved in an automatic, or semi-automatic, way?

Comment: not necessarily on openstreetmap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to get the wanted data via http://overpass-api.de or its web interface http://overpass-turbo.eu.

If not done yet, get familiar with its features and the most important search parameters via the OSM wiki at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo.

You can do numerical comparisons with "less or greater than" terms...

Your core query should contain the following:

```
node[natural=peak](if:t["ele"]>50)({{bbox}});
```

Also choose the wanted output format for that data, whether raw OSM data, GeoJSON, CSV listing or similar.

Comment: e.g. node[natural=peak](if:t["ele"]>300 && t["ele"]<500)({{bbox}});